# Can you include retina and non-retina images within the same sprite?

Tags: images, image-format, dpi, retina

When building a web page, I've always created 2 different sprites for my icons. A sprite for normal images and a sprite for retina images. The retina images are saved out twice the size and twice the DPI.

Example:

Normal icon - 50x50 at 72 dpi 
Retina icon - 100x100 at 144 dpi

Using a retina display media query in my CSS, I would target the icon and replace the background image with a retina one and also apply the appropriate background sizing property. (e.g. if the image is 100x100, background-size: 50px 50px).

Instead of having 2 separate image sprites, I decided to combine my images into 1 sprite. Using 72 DPI, I have a normal icon and beneath it I have an icon that is twice the size (for retina). This seems to work just fine on a web page.

Aside from performance in downloading a larger image file, is there any reason why I should have separate images for retina and non-retina? Does DPI actually matter when saving out for retina or does it just need to be twice the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic is rather complex, but I will try to summarize the most important things.

### DPI does not matter

The browser resizes the image according to the required pixel dimensions. DPI values will be ignored.

### Don't use multiple image sizes in a sprite sheet

Using lower resolution images saves bandwidth and results in a faster download. Using both sizes in the same file will not save a single byte, it will add bytes and therefore is a bad idea.

### Recommendations

1. Use high resolution aka retina images only and let the browser resize them.
2. Optimize all image files. BTW: A very good tool to optimize the file size of PNG images is [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com/).

Comment: Technically, a sprite sheet with progressively sized versions is called a *mipmap*. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MipMap_Example_STS101.jpg ) illustrates what Mario is saying about wasted bandwidth. However, the suggestion to only use a large size and stretch/downsize is also a wasted-bandwidth issue.

Comment: @Yorik you are right, it is not a perfect solution, but better than including both resolutions. :-)

Comment: I agree of course!

Comment: Can CSS not decide which size image to download based on the media query? Or will it download both images in every case?

Comment: @posfan12 if you provide different files for each resolution, then yes. If it is in a single file, as mentioned in the question, then no.